# Connecting and inserting data into mysql table using php

Tags: php

I am a PHP newbie and have been trying for sometime now to connect to MySQL database using PHP so I can insert data into a table I have created but I am unable to do this.

I suspect the problem is coming from my PHP `.ini` file,but that's just me.
Would be grateful if anyone can help me configure my PHP `.ini` file so I can connect to MySQL and insert data into my table. Here is my PHP script in case you are wondering.
Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

```
<?php

$host ="localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database1";
$table ="users";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database1",$con);


$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table(name,email,password)
VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]";

if(mysql_query($mysql)) die(mysql_error()); 
echo"Data inserted";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing HTML with PHP. They are two separate things. Get rid of all those <br /> you have in there. Then give it a try.

Comment: mysql_ functions are being phased out, look into mysqli_ and PDO. [first!]

Comment: Sammitch is right, of course, about the "mysql" statements. Here is a quick PDO tutorial (http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69284-using-pdo-for-database-access-beginner/#axzz2CFAGte3P). Run through this to get an idea of what you need to do. And, again, lose the "<br/>".

Comment: First, just copy and paste the code in http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp and after that, change the code step by step to make it what you want.

Comment: It's completely irrelated to `ini` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I revised some of your code this should work. You had a bunch of little errors. I suggest you read a couple tutorials on just connecting and the syntax of php.

Here is some really basic examples of connecting to a database: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Also once you get the hang of it here is a really good tutorial to teach you the OOP way of creating a class for a database:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql/

As far as I see this is not an ini issue. I hope this helps.

```
<?php
//Set your variables
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database1";
$table = "users";

//Make your connection to database
$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

//Check your connection
if (!$con) {
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

//Select your database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $con);

//Check to make sure the database is there
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use the db : ' . mysql_error());
}

//Run query
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(name,email,password) VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]'");

//Check Query
if (!$result) {
die("lid query: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Data inserted";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you have `<br/>` in your PHP statements? Remove all those.
Also, you have to use PDO or mysqli_ instead of the mysql_ library, mysql_ is deprecated.